# Calling a method in PCL from core project (MVVM core and Xamarin forms)

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

I'm using MVVMCross for DataBinding and following is my project structure.

```
->solution
-->Demo.Core
-->Demo (Xamarin PCL)
-->Demo.Android
-->Demo.iOS
```

How do i call a code available in the PCL project (Demo) in the core project (Demo.Core).

I use `Monkey.Cache` library in PCL to cache image's byte array. Now I want to move these code to Core project.

I'm looking for something like `DependencyService` which is used to call the Android code in PCL.

Comment: Does your Core project reference the PCL? If not then you cannot do that!

Comment: PCL doesn't refer the core. I thought there might as dependency service is able to do this. Thanks @FreakyAli

Comment: Can I ask you something? Why is it that you need something from PCL into Core? A method or what?

Comment: I wanted to know if a item exist in cache. Or else call an web API.

Comment: Will messagingCenter work in your project?

Comment: I have changed the architecture to handle the cache in the PCL itself @JackHua-MSFT